# Can you make a Github Action handle multiple repos or a seperate repo?

Tags: github, github-actions

I wish to grab the content from a PR description through `github.event.pull_request.body` and have the data there stored in a separate repo than the one the action is running on.

So can a Github Action write to a file/create a file in a separate repo than the one it is running in?

Comment: It can, but it needs a token. (@Nanu, your questions are very broad and don't show your own research. It would be better if you first read the docs, tried it on your own and then ask here for specific questions stating what you tried and how it did not work.)

Comment: See comment from @rethab. There is an action available that does this for you and it needs a token: https://github.com/LasyIsLazy/github-upload-action

Comment: Great solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60273343/how-to-use-github-actions-with-multiple-repositories-and-deploy-to-github-pages