# Implement GitHub Actions on organisation level?

Tags: github, github-actions

is it possible to implement a GitHub action on organizations level so that I don't have to do it for my 20 other repositories within the organization? Each repository should then inherit this GitHub action and execute it when the trigger is executed. Is such behavior currently possible?

The GitHub action is used for a security code analysis.

The GitHub action should be active on organisation level for all repositories without being defined for each repository.

Comment: If you're on GitHub Enterprise, you can set a Repository Rule that sets Required Workflows. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/required-workflows

Comment: Required workflows are being deprecated, but replaced with [rulesets](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-rulesets-for-repositories-in-your-organization). I added it to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub provides two options here:

**Reusable workflows**: Reusable workflows allow you to create Action configurations that you can call from another workflow and avoid duplication. This way you could configure your security analysis as a reusable workflow and then call it from all your repositories.

Generally to make a workflow reusable add the `workflow_call` to `on`:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
```

To find more details on how to build a reusable workflow I recommend checking [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#creating-a-reusable-workflow) and also [this blog post from GitHub](https://github.blog/2022-02-10-using-reusable-workflows-github-actions/).

**Starter workflows**: Starter workflows can be shared at an organisational level. They can be used as is or as templates and allow you or others to implement the same workflow faster and easier. Starter and reusable workflows can also be combined, so you can reference reusable workflows to make it possible to benefit from reusing centrally managed workflow code. Be aware if using github.com these are only available to public repositories within the organisation ([reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/creating-starter-workflows-for-your-organization#:%7E:text=Starter%20workflows%20created%20by%20users%20can%20only%20be%20used%20to%20create%20workflows%20in%20public%20repositories.)), they can be used in any repository on GitHub Enterprise ([reference](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/17597)).

Starter workflows need to be created in the `.github` repository of your organisation, in the `workflow-templates` directory.

More details on how to implement starter workflows can be found in [the documentation for these here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/sharing-workflows-secrets-and-runners-with-your-organization#sharing-workflows).

In addition, you can set up [required workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/required-workflows) to perform status checks on all of your organization's repositories, but this feature is being deprecated and moved to [rule sets](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-rulesets-for-repositories-in-your-organization), which allow you to define specific rules for repositories in your organization.

You can also find some similar questions e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60273343/how-to-use-github-actions-with-multiple-repositories-and-deploy-to-github-pages).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Jesse I've added a more detailed explanation.